# Why in $\mathbf{R}^2$ the only nontrivial subspaces are lines passing through the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra

I wonder why in $\mathbf{R}^2$ the only nontrivial subspaces are lines passing through the origin? Why not some other function (parabola, etc.) passing through the origin? I understand that for $P$ to be a subspace, it has to contain null vector. I do not understand, why it has to be a straight line.

Comment: These aren't *linear* subspaces.

Comment: If $x$ is an element of the subspace, then $rx$ has to be an element of the subspace for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$. $0,x,rx$ are colinear points. So, the full line from $0$ to $x$ must be inside the subspace. If two non-colinear points $x,y$ are inside the subspace, then for all points $z\in\mathbb{R}^2$ there are real numbers $r,s$ such that $rx+sy=z$. So, all points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be in the subspace.

Comment: I thought that vector space $\mathbf{R}^2$ can be understood as a set containing all possible combinations of ordered pairs (x, y), where x,y belongs to $\mathbf{R}$. Is my understanding correct? If so, than lets say I have a linear function $x + 2y = 0$. I cannot have an ordered pair for example (1,2) to meet the equality with number 0.

Comment: The linear function $x + 2y = 0$, where $(x,y)$ belongs to $\mathbf{R}^2$, represents a particular subspace of $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Comment: Since the ordered pair (1,2) cannot meet the equation, the subspace described by the function cannot be a subset $\mathbf{R}^2$ itself. Where am I not correct in my reasoning?

Comment: Why are you so fixated on $(1,2)$, when it’s not even in the subset of $\mathbb R^2$ defined by the equation $x+2y=0$?